# Transparent getJSON request does not work properly

Tags: ajax, getjson

I have stuck to make it work: after I put 2 getJSON strings ($.getJSON... ...return false) inside base64 function getjson request runs successfully but the rest of encode function does not return anything then (it must return base64 encoded text). How to fix it? Thanks.

Update: without 'return false;' getjson does not send anything, so that I think there would be a solution replacing 'return false;' to return something else, is not it?

Code:

```
var Base64 = {

// private property
_keyStr : "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=|", 
// public method for encoding
encode : function (input) {

       $.getJSON('http://debug.loc/savedata.php', $("#somedata").serialize(), function(data){});
       return false;


    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

    while (i < input.length) {

        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;

        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
            enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
            enc4 = 64;
        }

        output = output +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

    }

    return output;

},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected - actually, it returns value `false`, not "nothing".

The line `return false;` below the call to `getJSON()` effectively returns (exits) from the function. Returning from a function means that the rest of the code *does not* get executed.

I understand that you want the function to continue executing, encode given value and return it. For this to happen, simply remove the line `return false;`.